# How to Calculate the Amount of Floating Point Operations Needed to Train a Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, reinforcement-learning

Assuming a model with N parameters, arranged in an arbitrary architecture, training on M training examples for E epochs, how does one calculate within an order of magnitude or (hopefully) better the number of floating point operations needed to train that model?

I an find many numbers around the web for GFLOPS needed to train, but I'm not looking for FLOPS, I want the integral of FLOPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tldr; this is not possible.

Essentially, you're asking how many ops it takes to do a single forward and backward pass. It's not really possible to even estimate this based on the number of parameters. As an example, suppose you want to classify (binary) 1000x1000x3 images. A single fully connected layer would have 3 million parameters and cost roughly 3 million ops. A 3-filter 3x3 conv would have 81 parameters. If you stacked 37000 of these layers followed by a global pool, you'd also end up with roughly 3 million parameters, but it would take roughly 3 trillion ops to compute the result. If you embed some turing-complete submodule in your network (e.g. suppose one of your network layers is allowed to query a python interpreter), then there is no bound on the number of ops it would take to compute a single forward pass.

Comment: So if I'm looking to get an estimate from some tensorflow/pytorch model, what's the most straightforward way to get the number of ops? Seems like you're saying it's possible to calculate given the proper info about the model. I would assume that a tensorflow model architecture json file plus info on batch size & training examples would allow one to make this calculation?

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32809 tensorflow has this built in.